# WHERE Equivalents for SQL 'BETWEEN' and 'IN' in Agile Toolkit ATK4 DSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, atk4, agiletoolkit

I need help in ATK4 DSQL where i would like to retrieve only a specific
set of rows from my Employee Model Table class, using a Dynamic SQL.

can i generate an SQL BETWEEN or an IN clause in my WHERE statement
such that it would 'somehow' look like these constructs:

SQL **'IN'**:

*SELECT id,fnm,lnm,bp FROM emp WHERE id IN (1,3,5,7,9,11);*

```
$model=$this->add('Model_Employee');
$set=array(1,3,5,7,9,11);
$list=$mode->dsql()
   ->field('id')
   ->field('fnm') // first name
   ->field('lnm') // last name
   ->field('bp') // basic pay
   ->where('id in (%l)',$set) // only 1,3,5,7,9 & 11
   ->do_getAll();
```

SQL **'BETWEEN'**:

*SELECT id,fnm,lnm,bp FROM emp WHERE bp BETWEEN 3000 AND 5000;*

```
$model=$this->add('Model_Employee');
$min=3000;$max=5000;
$range=$mode->dsql()
   ->field('id')
   ->field('fnm') // first name
   ->field('lnm') // last name
   ->field('bp') // basic pay
   ->where('bp between %i and %i',$min,$max)
   ->do_getAll();
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated for current version of DSQL**: http://git.io/dsql

From the [documentation](http://dsql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/expressions.html):

```
$query -> where('time', $query->expr(
    'between [] and []',
    [$from, $to]
));
```

---

Old answer: in Agile Toolkit up to 4.1.* "where" is very limited to expressions. You would need to  write it like this:

```
->where('bp between '.
    $this->api->db->escape($min).' and '.
    $this->api->db->escape($max));
```

Comment: ha! i found something shorter and useful:

`->where(sprintf('bp BETWEEN  %d AND %d',$min,$max));`

Comment: that leaves the possibility for sql injection, though.